# Can I apply calculated gradient in tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

What I want to do is to simulate the back-propagation process on different machines, from one machine, I get the gradient from layer3 `d(layer3_output)/d(layer2_output)` as a numpy array, how am I able to get `d(layer3_output)/d(layer1_output)` efficiently given the gradient I received and passed to the previous layer?

Answer (score 1):

When you create your network and attach some loss you call **minimize** on the optimizer, which (under the hood) calls "apply_gradients". This function adds gradient computing ops to your graph. All you have to do is now request the op responsible for your partial derivative and pass the precomputed partial derivative through feed_dict option. Use tensorboard to visualize your graph and investigate names of gradients you are interested in. By default they will be in the "gradient" namescope, and naming of each op will be analogous to your operations, so something among the lines of `gradient/output_op:0` etc.

Comment: I know how to call optimizer when running on a single machine. However in my current case, I use different machine to store different layers as I want to train those layers asynchronously by the synthetic gradient, therefore I want to manage a way to apply the calculated gradient (in numpy array) to update the layer.

Comment: Implementing DNI? Then you need to go through "apply_gradients" function, since it gives you ability to apply arbitrary op as if it were actual gradient.

Comment: Thank you! Can I even back propagating the gradients of a few layers given the gradient on the top layer?

Comment: Yes, all you need to do with feed forward DNIs is to play around with "compute_gradients" and "apply_gradients", since "compute_gradients" gives you ability to backprop the rest of the gradients **starting** from arbitrary tensor (in your case - synthethic gradient). This is a real beauty of TF.

Comment: I am not fully understanding the use of "compute_gradients", as it give me some sense that I am "minimizing" something but actually I am not. What variables should I pass into the "computer_gradient" function? Do I have to pass every variables in the layers I want do back propagation?

Comment: You are minimizing something, this is the concept of the gradient (and backprop is **nothing else** but gradient computing method). And yes, you need to pass all the variables you want to "back prop to" to your compute_gradient, and also pass your "starting gradient" as "ys" parameter.